# Doubt about $\mathbb C\left[ X\times Y \right]$ and $\mathbb C\left[ X\right]\times\mathbb C\left[ Y\right]$ being isomorphic.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Here is my doubt. In case it's not clear what the notation in the title means, I'll report it here:

$\begin{equation*}\mathbb C\left[ X\right]\colon =\left\{ \sum\limits_{x\in X} a_x\cdot e_x\:\middle\lvert\:a_x\in\mathbb C\quad\forall x\in X \right\}\end{equation*}$

Where in $\mathbb C\left[ X\right]$ there is an $e_x$ for each $x\in X$. Specifically I indicate with it the set of formal linear combinations of symbols $e_x$, where two of them are the same one iff they share all the coefficients. We proposed in our class that this space is isomorphic to the set of functions $a\colon X\mapsto \mathbb C$ with compact support.

In my notes I read that there exists an isomorphism between $\mathbb C\left[ X\right]\otimes\mathbb C\left[ Y\right]$ and $\mathbb C\left[ X\times Y\right]$ if $X, Y$ are two non-empty, countable sets, that looks like this:

$\begin{equation*} \mu\left( a\colon X\times Y\mapsto \mathbb C \right)\end{equation*}\quad\colon \quad a\stackrel{\mu}{\longmapsto} \sum\limits_{(x,y)\in X\times Y} a(x,y)\;\delta_x\otimes\delta_y$

Where $\delta_x\colon X\mapsto\mathbb C$ maps $y\in X$ to $1$ iff $x=y$, $0$ otherwise, while $\delta_y\colon Y\mapsto\mathbb C$ maps $x\in X$ to $1$ iff $y=x$, $0$ otherwise.

Now, my uneducated mathematical mind has the following doubt: shouldn't $\delta_x,\delta_y$ be something in $\mathbb C\left[X\right]$ and $\mathbb C\left[Y\right]$ respectively? Like $\delta_x$ in my intuition should map $y\in X$ to $e_x$ iff $x=y$, $\:0$ otherwise and same thing for $\delta_y$. Am I tripping?

**EDIT**: Sorry, forgot to mention that in case $X$ is an infinite set, only a finite amount of coefficients $a_x$ is allowed to be non-zero.

Comment: Your $\mathbb C [X]$ is just the set of all functions $f:X\to \mathbb C$ right?

Comment: @ArcticChar: With the additional constraint of being with compact support, otherwise yes.

Comment: I can't see in your description of $\mathbb C[X]$ how it would imply that. Your definition of it do not involve topology of $X$ at all.....

Comment: @ArcticChar: You can associate to each linear combination in $\mathbb C\left[ X \right]$ a compact support application a that maps $x\in X\mapsto a(x)\colon= a_x$ i.e. it associates to $x\in X$ the corresponding coefficient in the linear combination. I forgot to mention that in the post, but in our class we allowed $X$ to be infinite but in that case only a finite amount of coefficients is allowed to be non-zero, hence $a$ can take only a finite amount of values.

Comment: Even when only a finite amount of $a_x$ is non-zero, the support might not be compact (it is finite though).

Comment: @ArcticChar If you actually have a topology, all finite sets are always compact.

Comment: @LukasBetz Yes indeed (thanks). But the problem is that, still, the definition above has not much to do with topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\delta_x$ are implicitly of the form you want them. Consider a formal symbol of the form $\sum a_x \cdot e_x$. We could think of this as a function $\mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{C}$ by considering $\sum a_x \cdot \delta_x$.

Conversely, a function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ that is non-zero at finitely many values corresponds to the element $\sum f(x) \cdot e_x$.